# Input tag, self closing tag?

Tags: html, forms, input, semantics

I reviewed W3school example on the form and the input types, here is the example:

```
<form>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

Now I see this a lot(even here on stackOverflow), that the input tag in  written with a forward slash at the end, to kind of close the tag. Like this :

```
<form>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname"/><br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname"/>
</form>
```

I tried both to see if there's a format that is refused and nor rendered, but apparently both worked. Now my question is both format "Formal" and servers best the "semantic and structure of my HTML document"? if not which one is the best to use from these perspectives ? and from which origin did the second format with the closing slash emerge ? is is deprecated from old HTMl version or what?

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, I know this was just for demonstration.